# No AWS placement groups on kops, is there another tool I could use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, kops

Kops is simple and does work great.

However, Kops does not seem to have support for placement groups
Look at the issue here 
https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/367

Is there another tool that anyone would recommend

Comment: Why can't you create a new placement group.?

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni i could, just that kops autocreates most of the k8s required objects in aws and can be scripted. Do not want to do do things manually if there is an alternative.

Comment: AWS has a Kubernetes Service in beta right now - you could look into that - https://aws.amazon.com/eks/

Comment: @noel great thanks, did not know that. Great will try thanks!